# How to animate drawing a line following a moving element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

So I want to draw a line behind a moving element.

The element starts at the bottom left of the screen and moves in a concave curve to the upper right.

I want to draw a dashed/dotted line behind this element, as though the element was a pen for example.

Here is a JS fiddle that should describe what I mean about the moving image etc. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jn9za5ez/8/

```
$('.plane').animate({
  left: 300,
  top: [50, 'easeInQuad']
}, 1800);
```

The above js is part of the post because I can't submit a jsfiddle link without providing code...

How would you suggest is the best way to approach this problem?

EDIT: The element is going to be something similar to a plane/rocket etc that slightly rotates along that curve, say from 45 to 0 degrees along the flight path, and I would like the dashed lines to follow that. Here is what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc4oP.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/jn9za5ez/16/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/jn9za5ez/16/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.plane').animate({
        left: 300,
        top: [50, 'easeInQuad']
    }, 
    {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function( now, fx ) {

        },
        progress: function(fx, progress) {               
          var x=getOffset(fx.elem);
          var lineid=Math.round(progress * 100);
          if($("#"+lineid).length==0){         
              $(fx.elem).after("<span id='"+lineid+"' class='line' style='top:"+x.top+"px;left:"+x.left+"px;'>.</span>");
          }
        }
    }); 

  function getOffset( el ) {
      var _x = 0;
      var _y = 0;
      while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
          _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
          _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
          el = el.offsetParent;
      }
      return { top: _y, left: _x };
  }
});
```

Style

```
.plane
{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:black;
}
.line{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: That's somewhat close to what I'm looking for. However I just noticed that I didn't put enough detail into my question. The element is going to be something similar to a plane/rocket etc that slightly rotates along that curve, say from 45 to 0 degrees along the flight path, and I would like the dashed lines to follow that. Here is what I mean:  [link](http://imgur.com/a/z37m2)